# numpy.searchsorted in a multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have got a three dimensional array with air pressure values in the form:

```
[[[1000 1010]
  [1005 990]]

[[950 960]
 [955 940]]

[[900 910]
[905 890]]]
```

The structure represents the pressure at different levels, so each element in the 2-d is ordered for each layer.

I would like to know at which level the pressure is 950 would be for each 2d element, getting a 2-d array with the index of the level for each element.

In a 1-D array like

```
a = [890, 940, 990]
```

I would use

```
a.searchsorted(950)
```

and the result would be 2, indicating that 950 would go at the 3rd position.

Is there a way to do it for all my array at once, without having to do it for each 2-d element?

Comment: I don't totally understand what you're after. If you take a single `(m,n)` array of pressure values corresponding to one level, are you saying that you want the rank of value `v` within the `(m*n,)` vector of sorted values for that level, e.g. `np.sort(A[0,:,:].flat).searchsorted(v)`? Then you just want to do the same thing for each level?

Comment: Well, I have multiple `(m,n)` arrays, one for each layer. I want to know between which levels a value would be, for each element in `(m,n)`. i.e. For the element [1][1], the value 950 would be between the layer 0 and the layer 1.

Comment: I see, so it must be the case that for a given point `A[:,i,j]` the pressure values increase monotonically across levels (otherwise what you're asking for doesn't make sense)

Comment: Yes. Since they are atmospheric pressures, the values are accumulative for each point in the surface.

Comment: If you can use PyTorch, it supports N-D arrays: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.searchsorted.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply the searchsorted function along an axis of your input array like this:

```
numpy.apply_along_axis(lambda a: a.searchsorted(950), axis = 1, arr = air_pr)
```

which should yield the intended result if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Thank you! It gave me the solution, which is numpy.apply_along_axis(lambda a: a.searchsorted(950), axis  = 0, arr = air_pressure)
The array must be passed with arr =, and the axis is 0 (I still have to understand why).
Also, the pressure values have to be ordered from lower to higher, but I think I will find a solution for that.

Comment: Ok. I had removed the 'arr =' to fit the command into one line, but of course Python will complain a non-keyword arg at that position.